# jquery loop to create dynamic-multiple vars

Tags: jquery, variables, for-loop

I am not sure if this is possible, but I want to create a multiple vars dynamically, for instance, these are the vars I create manually,

```
var left_1 = $('.column-global.left .item-global').eq(0);
var left_2 = $('.column-global.left .item-global').eq(1);
var left_3 = $('.column-global.left .item-global').eq(2);
```

but the problem is I only need two or one vars above sometimes. but three is the max.

so I am thinking of passing a parameter into the function to tell the code to create either 2 or 3 vars,

```
// I declare empty vars first
var left_1;
var left_2;
var left_3;

// get the number from somewhere, from the class for instnace
var last_class = $(this).attr("class").split(' ').slice(-1); 

// loop the number with for loop
for( var i = 1; i <= last_class; i++){
    left_1 = $('.column-global.left .item-global').eq(i-1);
}
```

but you notice that I am stuck - how can I loop the var in the {} of the for-loop?

basically I want the for loop to produce the multiple vars like these (same as above),

```
var left_1 = $('.column-global.left .item-global').eq(0);
var left_2 = $('.column-global.left .item-global').eq(1);
var left_3 = $('.column-global.left .item-global').eq(2);
```

is it possible??

thanks.

p.s.

some answers here suggesting an array, but I have another problem further...

bcos I also need to pass the vars into another function which is kept within that parent function like this,

```
another_function(left_1, left_2, left_3);
```

so how can I achieve this with the array?? thanks

Comment: Did you have some reason for not using an array?

Comment: how do I use an array for the situation above? thanks.

Comment: A jQuery object is (effectively) an Array. It doesn't make sense to store individually wrapped elements in an Array, when you already have them collectively wrapped in a jQuery Array.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of running the same selector 3 times and pulling out the item you want one at a time, why not just run it once and store that jQuery object?

```
var $globals = $('.column-global.left .item-global')
```

Then you can use whichever element(s) you need when you want.

```
$globals.eq(1).doSomething();
```

Or because a jQuery object is an Array-like object, you can get each individual DOM element by index, like:

```
$globals[1] // to get the actual non-jQuery wrapped DOM element
```

---

**EDIT:** With regard to the update in your question, first I'd rework the function if possible to accept 1 jQuery object.

If that is not possible, and you just need to pass individual arguments, I'd do one of two things.

**First idea.**

If possible, change the function so that it can accept DOM elements, then wrap them *inside* the function:

```
var $globals = $('.column-global.left .item-global');

another_function.apply( this, $globals.get() );

another_function(left_1, left_2, left_3) {
      // Wrap the DOM elements
    for( var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        arguments[ i ] = $( arguments[ i ] );
    }
    // ...the rest of the code
}
```

By calling your `another_function` [with `.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply), you're able to pass an Array of arguments, which will be assigned to the various parameters for the function.

Here we used [jQuery's .get() method](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to pass an Array of DOM elements.

**Second idea.**

If you absolutely *must* accept individually wrapped DOM elements, do the same as above, but create the Array of individually wrapped elements like this:

```
var $globals = $('.column-global.left .item-global').map(function() {
    return $(this);
});

another_function.apply( this, $globals.get() );
```

This uses `.map()` to create a jQuery object of jQuery objects, then uses `.get()` to pull the Array out of the object.

But really I'd change your `another_function` if possible.

Comment: thanks for this. I am working on it with your suggestions.thanks! :-)

Comment: @lauthiamkok - You're welcome. Let me know if you have questions. :o)

Comment: sorry, tried to make the $globals as you suggested but I still don't know how to get it right bcos I am passing a number of different vars into other functions from the parent function. u can have a look here on the functions I am working on - http://www.jsfiddle.net/7huET/

Comment: this is the outcome of the functions im trying to achieve, but these function only can apply to single circumstance/ page - i cannot apply them to other pages when I only need 2 vars. http://rokhsanafiaz.co.uk/news thanks!

Comment: @lauthiamkok - Could you take your last jsFiddle example, and give a little HTML so I can see the relationship between the elements? It seems like this should be able to be simplified. Perhaps give what it looks like to begin with, then what it should look like after the click.

Comment: thanks Patrick! I just put the basic structure of my html - http://www.jsfiddle.net/7huET/3/ the actually output of it is like this when it pulls the data from the database - http://rokhsanafiaz.co.uk/news

Comment: if u need the css, this is the newest with css in - http://www.jsfiddle.net/7huET/4/

Comment: @lauthiamkok - Did you change the class names on your page? I can't find `load-item-global 3` but I see `load-item-news` without a number after it. So I'm a little confused. It seems like you just want to move items from the right column to the left to make room for the expanded news item. If that's the case, instead of cloning, why not just `.append()` the items you want to the left column then re-order them in both columns when closing the current item? I've got to go for a while, but I'll stop back. If I'm not understanding the objective, then please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: sorry Patrick for the confusion. 'load-item-news' on the live site should be 'load-item-global 3' - I have not updated the site to the newest version yet. yes you are right - I just want to move items from the right column to the left to make room for the expanded news item. maybe I can use .append()  but how can I grab the items on the right I want to move them to the right without cloning them and then putting them back when closing the current item? any ideas are welcome. thanks so much!

Comment: i have another option which is using push(). then I can pass the array into other functions like this return_item(clone, right); have a look when you are free - http://www.jsfiddle.net/6ghAy/2/ but I still have the problem with push() bcos it suppose to produce 3 items in the array only, instead it produces 7 items in experiment 1 and 5 items in the experiment 2 - have I used the push() incorrectly? how can I fix it? thanks!

Comment: finally, i have got it right - http://www.jsfiddle.net/Kmar9/ only thing i don't understand is why I have to loop the index from 1 but not from 0. thanks!

Comment: @lauthiamkok - just stopping back for a minute, then I need to run again (busy day). Off the top of my head, without looking closer at the details, I would grab the ones on the right that you want to move to the left, add some temporary unique class to them, then `.append()` them to the left. Then when it is time to move them back, just select the ones on the left that have that unique class, remove the class, and `.append()` them back to the right. All the work of cloning, and hiding, and storing, etc, just seems like overkill. I'll take a closer look when I have more time. :o)

Comment: got the idea! thanks Patrick! thanks for the idea. I don't wish to hold you back so don't worry too much about this since I seem got it sorted for now. have a good day :-) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an array?

```
var left = []

for( var i = 1; i <= last_class; i++){
     left[i] = $('.column-global.left .item-global').eq(i-1);
}
```

or more likely, since arrays are 0-based:

```
for( var i = 0; i < last_class; i++){
     left[i] = $('.column-global.left .item-global').eq(i);
}i
```

Comment: sorry I need to pass the vars into another function like this,

Comment: loop_item(left_1, left_2, left_3); so how can I achieve this with the array?? thanks